# missing positional arguemnts , creating stack

Tags: python, stack

```
class Stack:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.pystack =[]
    def apnd(self, data):
        self.pystack.append(data)
Stack.apnd("PYTHON")
```

WHat AM I MISSING HERE. IT SAYS MISSING ONE POSITIONAL ARGUMENTS???? CREATING STACK

Comment: Forgot to instantiate an instance? `s = Stack() ; s.apnd("PYTHON")`

Comment: You are not creating a Stack object.  You need to create an object of that type before you can use the methods.